# Is there any programming language where you can forbid class casting of return types?

Tags: casting, programming-languages

### Background

Take this simple java class as an example:

```
class SomeWrapper {

    List<SomeType> internalDataStructure = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean hasSomeSpecificSuperImportantElement = false;
    // additional fields that do useful things

    public void add(SomeType element) {
        internalDataStructure.add(element);
        if (SUPER_IMPORTANT.equals(element)) {
            hasSomeSpecificSuperImportantElement = true;
        }
    }

    public Iterable<SomeType> getContents() {
        return internalDataStructure;
    }

    // additional methods that are definitely useful

}
```

Although it looks somewhat okay it has a big flaw. Because internalDataStructure is returned as is, callers of getContents() could class cast it to List and modify the internal data structure in ways they are not supposed to.

```
class StupidUserCode {

    void doSomethingStupid(SomeWrapper arg) {
        Iterable<SomeType> contents = arg.getContents();

        // this is perfectly fine
        List<SomeType> asList = (List<SomeType>) contents;

        asList.add(SUPER_IMPORTANT);
    }

}
```

In java and in other, similar programming languages, this problem can be solved by wrapping the internal data structure in some immutable wrapper. For example:

```
    public Iterable<SomeType> getContents() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(internalDataStructure);
    }
```

This works now, but has, in my humble opinion, a number of drawbacks:

- tiny performance drawback, not a big deal in all but the most extreme circumstances
- developers who are new to the language need to learn this immutable API
- developers of the standard library need to keep adding immutable support for all kinds of data structures
- The code becomes more verbose
- The immutable wrapper has a number of public methods that all throw exceptions. This is a rather dirty solution in my opinion because it requires additional documentation for users of the API.

### Question

Are there any programming languages where you can specify a return type of a method to be impossible to be class cast?

I was thinking of something like synthetic types where appending an exclamation mark ! to the end of a typename makes it un-class-cast-able. Like this:

```
    public Iterable!<SomeType> getContents() {
        return internalDataStructure;
    }

    void doSomethingStupid(SomeWrapper arg) {
        // The ! here is necessary because Iterable is a different type than Iterable!
        Iterable!<SomeType> contents = arg.getContents();

        // this now becomes a compile-time error because Iterable! can not be cast to anything
        List<SomeType> asList = (List<SomeType>) contents;

        asList.add(SUPER_IMPORTANT);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the point here is about mutability, the Java example of `List` vs. `Iterable` isn't a great example of mutable vs. immutable data types (the `Iterator.remove` method mutates the underlying collection, so the `List` could be corrupted by the external caller even without casting).

Let's instead imagine two types, `MutableList` and `ReadonlyList`, where `MutableList` is the subtype, and a `ReadonlyList` only prevents the user from mutating it; the list itself is not guaranteed to avoid mutation. (We cannot sensibly name the supertype `ImmutableList` because no value is both a mutable and an immutable list.)

---

Casting from the supertype to the subtype, e.g. from `ReadonlyList` to `MutableList`, is called [downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting). Downcasting is unsafe, because not every value of the supertype is a value of the subtype; so either a check needs to be performed at runtime (as Java does, throwing `ClassCastException` if the instance being casted does not have the right type), or the program will do something memory-unsafe (as C might do).

In theory, a language might forbid downcasting on the grounds that it is unsafe; popular programming languages don't, because it's convenient to be able to write code which you *know* is type-safe, but the language's type system is not powerful enough for you to write suitable type annotations which allow the type-checker to *prove* that the code is type-safe. And no type-checker can reasonably be expected to prove every provable property of your code. Still, in theory there is nothing stopping a language from forbidding downcasts; I just don't think many people will choose to use such a language for developing large software.

That said, I think the solution to the problem you describe would be simply not to make `MutableList` a subtype of `ReadonlyList`. The `MutableList` class can still have a method to get a read-only view, but since there would be no subtype/supertype relation, that view would not be a value of type `MutableList` so it could not be cast to the mutable type, even if you upcast to a common supertype first.

To avoid the performance cost at runtime, it could be possible for a language to have specific support for such wrappers to allow the wrapper to delegate its methods to the original list at compile-time instead of at runtime.

Comment: That is all nice and well known, but it doesn't really answer my question from my point of view.

Comment: It's difficult to give a direct answer to *"is there any programming languages where ..."* because all I can say is I'm not aware of any; I strongly suspect there aren't any non-esoteric languages, and there's a good chance there isn't an existing esoteric language with this feature either. But if the correct answer is "there are none" then I don't know who would be able to confidently say so and support their claim with evidence. The best I can do is suggest reasons why language designers wouldn't choose to have this feature.

Comment: You are probably right about that, but if enough people tell me that they are not aware of such a language (or a language with a different feature that accomplishes a similar goal) that would be enough for me. I thank you either way for your time and effort.

Comment: Sure. I think it's a good question, so I hope other people will write more answers.

Comment: @Nic What would be the practical use of knowing whether any such language exists? Is this one characteristic so fundamentally important to you that you'd consider switching languages just for that? Especially since that language will probably be pretty niche (as kaya3 can't think of any *popular* languages that have this characteristic), meaning it's probably badly supported, lacks libraries and an eco system etc. It's *much* more useful to talk about implications of this kind of design choice than to give you a concrete example of an implementation of it.

Comment: @deceze I did not ask this question because I want to use such a language. I am just curious. If there was such a language I would like to read up on its history and the thought behind it. Why does every question need a practical usage for the answer?